# jQuery append adds multiples of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this javascript which is used to add items to one of five columns. And the problem is when I click the add button, it adds one new item to the current column(the target), *as well as* each item already there.

First the code.

```
//adds the html code underneath the column. Get's called on document ready.
function populateTable(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        $("#maintable .control .c"+i)
            .append('<a href="#" class="add" onclick="addItem('+i+')">Add</a>');
}
//...
//and the function called onclick
function addItem(c,r,doRet,target){
    if(target == undefined)
        target = $("#maintable .schedtab .c"+c).get();
    if(r == undefined){
        r = $(target).find(".item").length + 1;
    }
    var $item = $('<div class="item cell' + cellAddress(c,r) + '"></div>');
    $item.append('<input type="text" class="packers"></input>');
    $item.append('<input type="text" class="cartons" ></input>');
    $item.append('<input type="text" class="count"></input>');
    $item.focusin(showCartonsSelect);
    $item.mouseenter(showCP);
    $item.mouseleave(hideCP);
    if(doRet) return $item;
    var $targ = $(target);
    $targ.append($item);
}
```

And here's the html:

```
<table class="schedule">
    <tr class="schedtab">
        <td class="col c1"></td>
        <td class="col c2"></td>
        <td class="col c3"></td>
        <td class="col c4"></td>
        <td class="col c5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="control">
        <td class="c1"></td>
        <td class="c2"></td>
        <td class="c3"></td>
        <td class="c4"></td>
        <td class="c5"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit:** Ok, here's an update. When I click the add button, which fires addItem(1), it generates a new "item", and then adds it to the target and to each item already there. Each item is a div with the class ".item". It is only supposed to add the new item to the target, not to each item already there.

Comment: is it ok that on click you only parse one variable? addItem('+i+')

Comment: yes, that is supposed to be handled in the code. Not implemented is inserting a new cell in the middle of the specified column. Only `c` is required.

Comment: I see you are using an index (i) for your jquery selector and to parse the variable, is the funtion addItem(c,r,doRet,target) inside a loop?

Comment: no, fixed the code sample. Both functions are directly in a javascript file.

Comment: When you say "as well as each item already there" you mean that it adds the new content without replacing the old content? If you want to replace the old content don't use append() use html(), maybe you already know this, I am just trying to understand your question. :)

Comment: Please create js fiddle for it. It will be lot more easier for us to understand what problem you are getting.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in a fiddle for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly maybe if you change `$targ.append($item)` for `$targ.html($item)` will fix your problem.

As you said: "it adds one new item to the current column(the target), as well as each item already there."

That is because `append()` adds content leaving the existing contents of the element.
`.html()` inserts and replaces any previous content.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake :) The problem is that cell address returns `A1 c1 r1` meaning `Cell A1, Column 1, Row 1`. So it adds the new item to each div that has the class `c1`, meaning appending it to each existing item in the column as well as the column itself. Anyway, thanks for your help. The reason it didn't do it in the fiddle was that I didn't include the cell address function.

So here's the updated fiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Arlen22/uzPDU/2/

And the updated code is: `target = $("#maintable .schedtab .col.c"+c).get();`